# content search not visible in visitor permission access

Tags: permissions, content-search-web-part

I using SP2013 & have used slideshow of content search web part, now when I give visitor permission to someone they can't see that slideshow i.e. content search web part doesn't show up, it shows

> "sorry , something went wrong."

I don't know what I have done wrong.

Comment: Make sure that the people with visitor permission also have read access to the List or Document Library items that you are displaying in the slide show. Also ensure that they have read access on the master page gallery where the display templates are stored (Also validate if the display templates are in published state).